# Trying to load data into mysql databse but keep getting error message

Tags: python, mysql-workbench, etl, mysql-python

DatabaseError: (mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError) 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host '@127.0.0.1' (11003)
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/4xp6)

```
engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector://root:****@@127.0.0.1:3306/pga', echo=False)

pga = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\micha\OneDrive\Desktop\PGA\ASA All PGA Raw Data - Tourn 
Level.csv', engine.connect())
```

Comment: Is there supposed to be 2 `@` symbols in there? I haven't used sqlalchemy, but that doesn't feel right and the error message suggests that it thinks the host is literally `@127.0.01` instead of `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: Hey yeah that is apart of my password as well... meant to leave that out

Comment: I'm glad you left it in, since it pointed to the problem. Did the link/duplicate question/answer help out?